# JQUERY onclick pass a callback after ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, callback

i have this 
`<a onclick="$('.element').hide(0); doMyMethod(_element = $(this));"></a>`

`doMyMethod()` is an ajax request, what i would like is to pass a callback when this method is finished i would like to `alert('somenthing');`

so i tryed with no chance:
`<a onclick="$('.element').hide(0,function(){doMyMethod(_element = $(this)); }, function(){ alert('somenthing');}); "></a>`

does anyone can help me?

Comment: Why can't you use the standard callback mechanism? If you need to be decorating or wrapping another callback, that is fairly easy in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass your alert('something') method to doMyMethod which should pass it to jquery's ajax as the callback.

Since your click is getting complicated, you may move it to it's own function.

```
function myClickHandler(item) {
  $('.element').hide(0);
  var callback = function() { alert('something'); };
  doMyMethod(_element = $(item), callback);
}

<a onlick="myClickHandler(this)"></a>
```

pass the callback as the "complete" callback http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

You can put it in the success of the ajax request.

```
function doMyMethod() {
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    data: '...',
    type: '...',
    //...
    success: function(data) {
        alert('something')
    }
    //...
});
}
```

Comment: nope sorry i need the ajax request to finish without any callbacks statments

Comment: Can you play with $.ajaxStart() and $.ajaxStop() ? Wait fot the ajax request to complete and execute your code. can you put your ajax in a global variable ? var method = $.ajax(...);